# JQuery cloned page links not functioning

Tags: jquery, clone, hyperlink

I'm dynamically creating page links at the top of my page. Once all the work is done, I clone the page links wrapper into a div located on the lower page. The problem is, the cloned page links do nothing when clicked. Is this even possible if the elements are being cloned? Or how could I copy my page links to the bottom of the page as well?

```
<div id="pages"></div>

<div id="workspace"><br/></div>

<div id="pagesclone"></div>

//create the page links
for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    $('#pages').append(' <a href="#" class="links">' + x + '</a> ');    
}

//function for when a link is clicked
$('.links').click(function() {
   current = $(this).html();
   $('#workspace').html('You clicked ' + current);
});

//clone to the lower page
$('#pages').clone().appendTo('#pagesclone');
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JshnC/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clone events as well, pass in `true` into the parens:

```
var foo = $(bar).clone(true);
```

You can go much deeper, and clone events of children too with the second parameter:

```
var foo = $(bar).clone(true, true);
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

#### Warning

I see that you're using id attributes on your elements - `.clone` will result in duplicate ids being used in your document. If at all possible, avoid using id's in favor of classes on elements that will be cloned.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. Does it matter I am cloning the IDs of certain elements, like NEXT/PREV buttons? Should I use a class instead, or will they still function fine? Edit: Your edit beat me to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Norse I would avoid having duplicate ids, as you can and will find some unpredictable and unfavorable behavior. I would instead use classes if you can.